# What is a short common name and tag for C++ Standard Library on SO?

Tags: discussion, tags

I often have to write in comments C++ Standard Library which is long for comments. Is there a standard abbreviation for it, since `std` is not C++ Standard Library, it is a namespace.

Do we have some tag for C++ Standard Library questions? For example, when I want to ask questions to be solved with C++ Standard Library, not with all `std` which includes, for example, 'ranges'?

Comment: Isn't it [tag:stl]?

Comment: @TylerH, absolutely not. Please see the [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: The C++ standard library is part of C++. If you want something solved with it then tag... C++?

Comment: @DamirTenishev So then the [tag:std] tag looks like it is the tag to use for that. As the tag says, "for the library _and_ its namespace".

Comment: We also have tags for some specific parts of the library, such as [tag:std-ranges] that applies to your specific example here.

Comment: We have [[tag:STL]] and [[tag:std]]; I assume one is correct.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, it helps, thank you. How can I stress in the question and its tag that I want to limit the solution with C++ standard library? People start using 'ranges' and other stuff which belongs to C++ tag, but doesn't belong to C++ Standard Library

Comment: @TylerH, is doesn't work, since `std` tag covers std namespace which includes lots of things like 'ranges' and so on, which are not part of C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, 'std-ranges' is exactly what I want to **exclude**, see my original question (not with all std which includes, for example, 'ranges').

Comment: @ThomA, `stl` is about library that was written back in 1990th and need to be installed separately. People often confuse STL with C++ Standard Library with borrowed many ideas from STL, but which is not STL. The `std` doesn't work by the reasons I mentioned in the previous comments.

Comment: Why do we need a specific tag that excludes std-ranges?

Comment: So you want a standard library defined by *your* definitions, not the standard's? There's no tag for that, nor should there be.

Comment: @KevinB, because standard library doesn't include ranges and we don't have tag for it. We have tags for: stl - absolutely different library, std - namespace with **includes** ranges and many other stuff; and we have nothing for C++ Standard Library,

Comment: @ThomA, why? We put in one `std` two different things: **C++ Standard Library** and **namespace**. They are different and if I want something that should be implemented only with **C++ Standard Library** I have no way to tag it.

Comment: @ThomA, I am not asking to create, I am asking if it exists. If not, how to ask questions, see my comments under the answer below.

Comment: To which you've been advised of [[tag:stl]] and [[tag:std]].

Comment: *"because standard library doesn't include ranges"* - What!? It very much includes ranges. It includes them since C++20. The fact they are in a nested namespace does not make them less a part of the standard library.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, end of story. My bad. Confused things. Anyway, there is still a lot of stuff (see my comment below the answer) which don't.

Comment: What's so special about C and C++, anyway, that we would want a tag for *their* standard libraries, but not for the standard library of any other programming language?

Comment: `std` or `stdlib`, where `stdlib` has been synonymized to `std`, but strikes me as more descriptive.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, nothing. I just asked to avoid issues. If no, then no.

Comment: @user4581301, what do you mean with `stdlib`? Just to use it in the text? Because there is no such a tag. Again, how to make sure that stdlib refers to C++ stdlib, not to C stdlib? Just out of context of the other tags and question itself?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I mean for use as a tag, but it's possible that `stdlib` was absorbed completely into `std` and purged.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the clarification you've provided, your request is illogical. Tags are inclusive, not exclusive. A tag for [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) means "this question is about the Standard Library and/or its namespace". It does not mean "this question is about *nothing but* the Standard Library".

If you want to ask a question about the Standard Library, but are specifically looking to avoid the ranges feature within the Standard Library, use the [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) tag and simply explain in your question that you want to avoid that feature.

Comment: So, you are saying that I should tag question with `std` and then in my question list **all** components of `std` which I don't want to use in the solution which are parts of `std` namespace? Like, please don't use: `std::forward_list`, `std::ranges`,`std::vector<bool>`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::experimental::lexicographical_compare_3way`, etc., etc.? What is the way to create a correct question?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Yes, if you really need to use _some_ part of `std` but not others. Depending on your criteria, it may be easier to simply list in the question which parts you _can_ use. Note that, in such unusual circumstances, you will probably get requests for clarification as to _why_ you can't use so many _standard parts_ of the relevant programming language, because that's akin to being given a hammer and told "now you can only use this hammer on X type of nails, not the other 25 types of nails out there" (AKA a silly, nonsense requirement).

Comment: This will end up with people wasting lot of time and being angry because the initial question didn't state that `std::unordered_set` mustn't be used and this could come with **any** part of the answer. Well, let's see in action.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Why wouldn't the initial question state that? My recommendation is literally _to state that_, if it's a requirement. **All** questions should state **all** of their requirements upfront. If that's too much for you to fit into a question, maybe Stack Overflow is not the right place to get help; you might consider hiring a C++ consultant, instead. Bear in mind that questions on Stack Overflow should be specific and practical questions. "How do I import only 40% of the C++ standard library" (for example) does not sound very practical.

Comment: ... or useful to other people.

Comment: And it's a <air_quotes><sarcasm>[solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301)</sarcasm></air_quotes>.